# Passing an argument into a function as a parameter of a function call

Tags: javascript, mobile, cordova

This is probably more of a JavaScript question but I'd like to pass another parameter in the getPicture_Success function argument here:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(getPicture_Success, null, options);
```

The getPicture_Success function's signature is getPicture_Success(imageData).

I'm trying to do 2 different things depending on where in the app the photo is needed - rendering the image on a different screen for each.

I'd like to pass another argument into it, like getPicture_Success(imageData, appScreen), for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageData) {
    getPicture_Success(imageData, 'Screen 1');
}, null, options);
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, I can't remember where I read about passing functions as arguments though! Cheers

Comment: You can pass functions as parameters, that's what you did in your code example. But instead of changing the implementation of navigator.camera.getPicture(), you just pass an anonymous function as a parameter, which you can control better.