# how to call a function with passing parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to pass the event to function in javascript suppose. i am fire function from two input. then how i can call the event with passing parameter.

can i do this using calling and without binding event in jQuery.

Comment: Keyword: "closure" (although this can be wrapped in many different ways.)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300242/javascript-passing-a-function-with-parameters-as-a-parameter and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429328/passing-an-argument-into-a-function-as-a-parameter-of-a-function-call for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
function DoCSSStuff(param1,param2)
{
     $(param1).css('height', param2);

};
```

That way you could call the css function to manipulate height with passed parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but here's an example of passing a function with parameters as a callback:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    return myFunction(false, 3);
}, 1000);
```

You wrap your function call in an anonymous function wrapper.